# Using watch or ng-bind in angular but with "Controller as" methodology

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm learning AngularJS without using $scope, just using "this" as "Controller as controlInstance" method.

I've a websocket that receives a message and when that happens, I change a value and I must show it on the DOM at real time.

Basically I've this:

```
angular.module('wolfie.wSocket', [])
    .controller('wolfie.wSocketController', function() {
        var soquete = this;
        soquete.sockstate = "OFF";
        soquete.socket = new WebSocket(URL_WEBSOCKET_SERVER);
        soquete.socket.onopen = function (ev) {
            console.log("OPEN");
            soquete.sockstate = "Connection Open";
            soquete.getStatus();
        };
        soquete.getStatus = function() {
            console.log("TEST GET STATUS");
            console.log(soquete.sockstate);
            return soquete.sockstate;
        };

...
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="wolfie.wSocketController as webSocket">
{{webSocket.sockstate}}
```

So how can I show the soquete.sockstate property when it changes?
`{{soquete.sockstate }}` doesn't work

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the alias you specify for the controller instance:

E.g.

```
<div ng-controller="wolfie.wSocketController as someAlias">{{someAlias.sockstate}}</div>
```

Additionally, since `sockstate` is updated outside of the Angular context, you need to make Angular aware of the change using `$scope.$apply()` (for which you'll also need the `$scope` of course):

```
.controller('wolfie.wSocketController', function ($scope) {
    ...
    soquete.socket.onopen = function (ev) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            console.log("OPEN");
            soquete.sockstate = "Connection Open";
            soquete.getStatus();
        });
    };
});
```

**UPDATE FROM AUTHOR, in comments:**

There is no way to do it without $scope. $scope is there implicitly anyway (ng-controller="x as y" basically does: $scope.y = this). The advantage of using the controllerAs syntax is being more declarative in the view and being able to access properties when using nested controllers (or to be more clear about whose controller properties you are accessing).

Comment: Yes, I use it:<div ng-controller="wolfie.wSocketController as webSocket">
{{webSocket.sockstate}}

Comment: but still not update the dom when the property updates

Comment: ok but I'm not using $scope, I'm using "this" instead. So that was the point of my question, how could I do it without using $scope? There is a way? If not, why using "this" instead $scope come back to my search of answers. In everywhere I saw that is better "this" than $scope :S

Comment: @Leandro: There is no way to do it without `$scope`. `$scope` is there implicitly anyway (`ng-controller="x as y"` basically does: `$scope.y = this`). The advantage of using the `controllerAs` syntax is being more declarative in the view and being able to access properties when using nested controllers (or to be more clear about whose controller properties you are accessing).

Comment: Thanks a lot Expert System. Now is clear to me what is the difference between scope and this :) You honor your nickname!